# Redirecting a buddyboss profile tab to a different tab if not subscribed to a specific membership

Tags: plugins, php, redirect, profiles

If the user is subscribed to one of the three memberships, they have access to the visitors profile tab ([www.site.com/members/user/visitors](http://www.site.com/members/user/visitors)) but if they are not subscribed, if they click on the visitors profile tab they shouldn't be allowed to access it and should instead be redirected to a different tab called Premium ([www.site.com/members/user/premium](http://www.site.com/members/user/premium)).

```
   if(current_user_can('memberpress_product_authorized_853' || 'memberpress_product_authorized_1007' || 'memberpress_product_authorized_1008')) {
  // Do authorized only stuff here
}
else {
  // Do unauthorized stuff here
    
    if( bp_get_requested_url() == (bbp_get_user_profile_url() . "/visitors")) {
        function visitors_redirect() { 
         bp_core_redirect( bbp_get_user_profile_url() . "/premium");
    }
    

}

    add_action('visitors_redirect');

}
```

However, using this code, the site goes into some form of maintenance mode and gives me the error: "There has been a critical error on this website".